# Edit script for dynamic form data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a grading system, and I have many tables with the prefix rubrics_. Each table has skills for different categories of grading.

I have a form being looped, which displays all skills that have been created for this particular assessment document.  The input fields are populated with whatever information they entered when creating the "rubric. (hence the value $row2['skill']).  I named the field evidence_[unique id] to try and identify each skill value.

```
$sql2 = "select * from rubrics_evidence where rubricid = '$id'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die (mysql_error());
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo "<tr><td><input type='text' value='".$row2['skill']."' name='evidence_".$row2['id']."' size='100' /></td></tr>";
}
```

My objective is to make it so these skills are edited when a new value is entered (appending the existing value). However, by naming each skill with something like evidence_[id], I'm not sure how to take that data and process it.

What I mean by that is, I can't figure out how to reprocess these input fields once they are submitted.  I can't tell the script to look for evidence_id because each id is unique.

Anyone know how to accomplish this? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the field names in your processing code the same way you created them

```
//make sure you include the $id from that form somewhere in the form again
$sql = "SELECT id FROM rubrics_evidence WHERE rubricid = " . $_POST['id'];
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $value = $_POST['evidence_' . $row['id']];
    //do something with the new value
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. You're excellent at interpreting my rambling. If you'd be interested, I'd love to discuss the possibility of paying you to help structure some of my spaghetti code in a more organized manner.